# Smallest GIS library for embedded devices?

Tags: python, linux

I need to use very simple geometry operations (read SHP or other standard format and simple searches) within an embedded device running a simple linux based os.

What is the smallest and simplest API I could use?

It could be written in C/C++ or Python in order to allow the integration with my system.

Thanks,

Samuel

Comment: do you care about licensing?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [Shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/). It's a small C library for simple shapefile manipulation.

Answer (score 6):

I can't make any claims about 'smallest' but a couple options are:

- [PySAL](http://code.google.com/p/pysal/): Python Statistical Analysis Library.  It can read shapefiles natively. You could include only the modules you need.
- [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/index.html): Store your data in a spatially-enabled SQLite database. SpatiaLite includes a feature called '[virtual shapefile](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/shapefile.html)' that allows you to directly access a shapefile and query it as if it were a database table without actually importing it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple python tool here:
http://www.axismaps.com/code.php

Answer (score 3):

There has been some talk and proposal of such by the qgis community. see it here...
[QGIS Wiki](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011)

Answer (score 2):

What about [pyshp](http://geospatialpython.com/2010/11/introducing-python-shapefile-library.html) and [shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)? It is simple, efficient and [well](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python%20Shapefile%20Library/0.9) [documented](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/).

Comment: +1 although you'll need the GEOS C++ library as well as Shapely on the device

Comment: pyshp is a very minimalistic python file: `shapefile.py`